# android insists i don't have a column in my database table

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

i can't figure out this strange error while i try to insert value into database

ERROR

```
01-01 15:48:56.065  10056-10056/com.autophone E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) table mainTable has no column named status_date
01-01 15:48:56.100  10056-10056/com.autophone E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting status_date=1 בינו 2000 15:48:56 problem=non model=N9005 phone_number=123 in_date=1 בינו 2000 15:48:56 status=received name=ian
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table mainTable has no column named status_date (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO mainTable(status_date,problem,model,phone_number,in_date,status,name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

the main point it says i don't have "status_date" in the main table
but how is it possible?

```
  public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;

    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";//1
    private static final String KEY_MODEL = "model";//2
    private static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER = "phone_number";//3
    private static final String KEY_PROBLEM = "problem";//4
    private static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";//5
    private static final String KEY_IN_DATE = "in_date";//6
    private static final String KEY_STATUS_DATE = "status_date";//7

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDb";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "mainTable";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL =
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE
                    + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + KEY_NAME + " text not null, "
                    + KEY_MODEL + " text not null, "
                    + KEY_PHONE_NUMBER + " text not null, "
                    + KEY_PROBLEM + "text not null, "
                    + KEY_STATUS + "text not null, "
                    + KEY_IN_DATE + "text not null, "
                    + KEY_STATUS_DATE + "text not null "
                    +");";
```

here it is...

this is the enter part

```
 long newID=myDB.insertRow(new LogEntery("ian","N9005","123","non"));
```

logentery is a class i use that also adds the rest for the data

```
public LogEntery(String name,String model,String phone_number,String problem)
    {
        super();
        this.name=name;
        this.model=model;
        this.phone_number=phone_number;
        this.problem=problem;
        this.in_date = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        this.status_date = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        this.status = "received";
    }
```

by the way... how do i change getDateTimeInstance to get DD/MM/YYYY only and not the full data/time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common source of error is the database version.

If you ran your app at least once without the `KEY_STATUS_DATE` field in your table, and then added that field and ran your app, the table won't be updated (`onUpgrade()` will not be called), because the system thinks that the database hasn't changed.

Try raising the version.

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

With this, the system will think "*Oh, there's a new version of the database, let's call onUpgrade()*". Ideally from this method, you delete your tables an call `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` manually, or execute some DDL statements to add the missing field.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your database in your phone to see if it is real that no column named  status_date.

Solution to your ＂by the way＂:

SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dateString = dateFormatGmt.format(new Date());

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to start with a basic schema that works, then write your abstraction layer. I'd take a step back and make sure that all of the assumptions are correct.

For example, there are 4 arguments to your constructor, while there are 8 columns in your table and 7 setters being called in the constructor. Looks like you might just be off-by-one, at a glance. If not, its still a little confusing. I'd either require all parameters for the statement in the constructor, or mark the optional fields in some way (i.e. overloaded method calls with a no-args constructor, etc).

Hope my input is helpful.

Brandon